# vim (7.4) command line does not display on win8.1 64 bit

Tags: vim, windows-8.1, 64-bit, cygwin

The vim (7.4) command line does not display  on win8.1 64 bit in mintty, rxvt, or command prompt windows.

I am using the same config files on win8.1 as on win7, where vim displays correctly (same versions of everything except windows).

emacs-nox has a similar command line widow that displays with no problem in those 3 terminals.

versions:
win8.1 64 bit

$ uname -srv

CYGWIN_NT-6.3-WOW64 1.7.32(0.274/5/3) 2014-08-13 23:03

$ bash --version

GNU bash, version 4.1.10(4)-release (i686-pc-cygwin)

$ mintty --version

mintty 1.1.3

$ vim --version

VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Aug 28 2014 01:24:00)
Included patches: 1-417
Compiled by

$ rxvt --version

rxvt: bad option "--version"
Rxvt v2.7.10 - released: 26 MARCH 2003
Options: XPM,transparent,utmp,menubar,multichar_languages,scrollbars=rxvt+NeXT+x
term,frills,linespace,24bit,selectionscrolling,256colour,.Xdefaults

Skip

Comment: What do you mean by vim command line does not display? (Picture of expected and actual?)

Comment: This is more complicated than I first thought. The command line I was referring to was the --INSERT-- that appears at the bottom of the window in insert or append mode. In win8.1 it does not override the file name, and that line appears mimic the command buffer if the ist char is ":" fiilling up from the bottom. I need to investigate further to make a sensible description of the behavior.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18115644/vim-has-many-ui-bugs-on-cygwin-on-windows-8

Comment: I checked my win7 host and it did indeed have a .vimrc file. When I hid it the vim invocation had the same issue I posted about.